# Calling Asynchronous REST method in WebApi appears as method not found

Tags: android, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have Web Api with the following method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Complete(__ServiceComplete ServiceCompleteInfo)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

                // Send SMS to User for completion
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                SmsBL blSms = new SmsBL();
                blSms.SendServiceCompleteSms(ServiceCompleteInfo.ProposalId, ServiceCompleteInfo.CallId);


                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

        return response;
    }
```

The `SendServiceCompleteSms` function is Asynchronous.

Now, I call this function from an android app, and I monitor everything using debugger.

If I comment the line and not calling SendServiceCompleteSms  I receive Http.OK response in my android app.

If I uncomment `SendServiceCompleteSms` then an SMS is sent and I can see that the method returns `Http.OK` from the server. However, inside the Android I get `Java.io.FileNotFoundException`, Http code 'Internal server error' (500) as if the method is not found.

Any idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not that the method is not found, `the SendServiceCompleteSms method` is throwing an exception.

Also, you said that the `SendServiceCompleteSms` method is asynchronous, but you are calling it synchronously.  Better to do it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CompleteAsync(__ServiceComplete ServiceCompleteInfo)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            // Send SMS to User for completion
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            SmsBL blSms = new SmsBL();
            await blSms.SendServiceCompleteSms(ServiceCompleteInfo.ProposalId, ServiceCompleteInfo.CallId);


            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you.